# cakephp check if methods or functions exist and redirect accordingly

Tags: php, cakephp

trying to write a method for my cakephp app that checks if the method called in the url doesnt exist, and redirects the user based on their account type if the method holds true or not. Is this even possible? *where a user can simply override my url like \localhost\www\project\user\method\ID affected by method*

trying to use the built in php function method_exists for such. and if it is possiblem how would i go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you call a non-existent controller or action, CakePHP will throw a `MissingControllerException` or `MissingActionException` and a 404 error accordingly. You can react on that however you want. You can [create your own exception handler](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html#create-your-own-exception-handler-with-exception-handler) and catch any `MissingControllerException` or `MissingActionException`and then handle it from there.

Or you can check for the status code in the response object from your AppController, which is technically not as "clean" as actually handling the exceptions, but gets the job done without too much effort anyway. To do that, in your AppController, add:

```
public function beforeRender() {
    if ($this->response->statusCode() == '404') {
        // We've hit a 404, do whatever you want to do here...
    }
}
```

In there you can check the Session / AuthComponent to see what kind of user you're dealing with and redirect them according to your wishes.